# Is Project number under settings tab the client_id?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-api-client, google-api-js-client

https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/settings/project?project=my-Project-ID

I am trying to use api_key and client_id for

```
const authOptions = {
  client_id: `${client_id}.apps.googleusercontent.com`,
  scope: 'profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'
};
window['gapi'].auth2.init(authOptions);
```

PS: I tried to folllow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o425vQXpigw) but seems console now is different, no tab to create client_id like before

Comment: Client id and client secret are for Oauth2 to allow you to access private user data.    Api key is used for accessing public data.   The code is different depend upon what you are trying to do.   Which language are you using?   is this javascript library code?

Comment: yes it's javascript. trying to use youtube API's from a angular app. but where is the code shown?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiclientsetapikeyapikey

Comment: I don't there there is ready made getClientId API.